# Dynamic checkboxes with the help of PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm checking the database and if a particular string is matched, the respective `checkbox` gets checked but the error is whenever a string is matched, I'm getting two `checkboxes` checked, one `unchecked` and another `checked`.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
     $result = mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FROM grsi "); 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $focus=explode(",",$row['spr']);
?>
<input type="checkbox" value=<?php echo $row['spr']; if(in_array("Cricket",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> name="focus[]" />Cricket
<?php
     }
  exit();
?>
```

Comment: Show output of this `while`, check your database records.

Comment: my output a unchecked checkbox followed by cricket and a checked checkbox followed by cricket

Comment: what u_mulder means i guess is the example contents of `$row['spr']`

Comment: i am having just one row in my database which contains Cricket in spr  column

Comment: What is the output Html you are getting?

Comment: any good if you echo checked instead: `if(in_array("Cricket", $focus)) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['spr']; ?>" <?php if(in_array("Cricket",$focus)) { ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?> name="focus[]" />Cricket
```

I hope this will work properly. Please let me know if it didnt work.

Comment: i tried your answer but still the same issue one unchecked and another checked checkbox

Comment: Please check the Result Array may have duplicate entry too.

Comment: GOT IT , mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Comment: Actually mysqli_fetch_array will return bot associative and index result array so if the result row no is 1 it will return 2. 1 for associative and another for indexed element. This is the actual issue with you.

Comment: but he's just checking `$row['spr']`, not `for ($x in $row)...`, tho i agree `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is probably more efficient

Comment: Actually the issues with the while loop where it is fetching the array, And it is returning double of what he is expecting.

Comment: Great, I am overwhelmed. Let me know if you ave any issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
 $result = mysqli_query($sql,"SELECT * FROM grsi "); 
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $focus=explode(",",$row['spr']);
  if(in_array("Cricket",$focus)) {
 ?>
<input type="checkbox" value=<?php echo $row['spr'];  ?> checked="checked"  name="focus[]" />Cricket

<?php
}else{
?>
  <input type="checkbox" value=<?php echo $row['spr'];  ?> name="focus[]" />Checkbox name
<?php
}
}
exit();
```

?>

Comment: still the same issue :-(

Comment: May i know string in your database

Comment: my string in spr is Cricket

Comment: So no need to exploding the string "$focus=explode(",",$row['spr']);
  if(in_array("Cricket",$focus))" instead of these try only "if($row['spr']=='Cricket')"

Answer (score 1):

Your input checkbox is inside your while loop which means if there are 2 rows from the database, there will be 2 input boxes.

And based on you SQL statement, you are selecting all records(there is no WHERE statement). So if there are 10 rows in your table, there will be 10 input box. Make sure you will only select the row that you need.

Comment: on your suggestion, i tried adding another product in database and on executing above code i got 4 checkboxes 2 unchecked and 2 checked